# Getting error when using post method in form

Tags: html, jsp, struts, html-select, idempotent

I am getting null when I am using post method while passing a form to the next page
A repeat of this question 
[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304348/accessing-a-form-variable-inside-javascript)

```
<html>
<head>
Title
<script>
function callme()
{        
alert("Hi");         
alert(document.getElementById("prio").value);       
}
</script>   
</head>
<body>
<FORM method="post" name="test"enctype="multipart/form-data" action="testjsp.jsp" >
<select name="prio" id="prio"> 
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick=callme();>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

IN testjsp.jsp I am trying to prin the prio variable which I am not able to do and its prining null.I just want to access the variable prio in some other server side component and also want to use post method.

```
<html>
<head>
Title  
</head>
<body>
<%
String prio=request.getParameter("prio");
out.println("the value of prio is"+prio);
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Is this any way related to Idempotent property?
I am confused why I could not access the variable prio in the testjsp page.

Answer (score 1):

You are encoding your request as `multipart/form-data`, often used to upload files. The servlet container does not include support to automatically decode this data, only `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data (the default). To use `multipart/form-data` you need a 3rd party MIME parser like [Apache commons fileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/).